# ThisWorkbooks.Sheets.Formula = addition between 2 cells and a number

Tags: excel, vba

In Sheet1, L13 is a difference between 2 other cells (I10 - H85). In the first time, this difference is great than zero (e.g. 1470000.43)

In Sheet1, H85 is a additional of some cells. One of this cells is H82. H82 = 'Sheet2'!C14 + 'Sheet2!'G14.

Now, in the second time, I must add the difference (L13 value) in H82, such as L13 becomes 0. The formula on H82 must like this: 'Sheet2'!C14 + 'Sheet2!'G14 + 1470000.43

The format of the cells is Standard (with 2 decimals).
Warning: my MS-Excel is french!!!

For this, I tried:

- to cast to Double (CDbl) or decimal (CDec) for ecart only and for each term of addition;
- to Format ecart like `ecart = Format(ecart, "#,##")`

but don't works: error d'execution 1004: Erreur definie par l'application ou par l'objet.

For this, only things that works is this:

```
Dim ecart As Double
ecart = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L13").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H82").Formula = _
                    "='Sheet2'!C14 + 'Sheet2!G14 + " & int(ecart)
```

but, L13 becomes 0,43 (because ecart is cast to int and the decimals are not taken in account)

I really don't know how can fix this.

Comment: Yeeees, this is it! It works! The variable that took the value of L13 is of type Double. I added a variable of type Variant = Replace(L13 value, ",", "."), then used in H82 formula. I hope to help someone else. Cheers!